# how to make a heatmap from TCGA?

Tags: r

i had a lot of trouble when dealing TCGA data, how to make a heatmap?

```
a <- c(1,2,2)
b <- c(333,73,382)
c <- c(881,5,5)
wd<- data_frame(a,b,c)
colnames(wd) <- c("TCGA-55-8615-01A","TCGA-97-8177-01A","TCGA-86-8674-01A")
rownames(wd) <- c("UPK3B","GPM6A","LGI3")
wd
```

example: data :wd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to do it using `heatmap`. This requires your data to be a numeric matrix, so you could do:

```r
heatmap(as.matrix(t(wd)))
```

[image]

If you want full control over the appearance and theme elements, you can use `ggplot`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

wd %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  pivot_longer(-1, names_to = "TCGA") %>%
  ggplot(aes(rowname, TCGA, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile(color = "white") +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = 10) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)
```

[image]

---

**Reproducible data taken from question**

```r
wd <- data.frame("TCGA-55-8615-01A" = c(1, 2, 2),
           "TCGA-97-8177-01A" = c(333, 73, 382),
           "TCGA-86-8674-01A" = c(881, 5, 5),
           row.names =  c("UPK3B", "GPM6A", "LGI3"),
           check.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: thanks. it succeed. i used ggplot. however, my data is 50*587. and the plot become something like this,what can i do when there are too many rownames and colnames :https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcUl9.jpg

Comment: @YiHaoChen you need to remember that a plot is a way to display data in a way that makes your data clear and understandable, You simply cannot have a heatmap with 500 labelled rows: It will be completely uninterpretable, so you need a different way of diplaying the data. Perhaps 10 separate plots of 50 * 50 heatmaps would be better, or find some way of summarizing your data that isn't a heatmap